# Back button refreshes/reloads uipickerview content

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I downloaded a project that I am trying to learn how to use SQLite3 with.
The way the author wrote it, they use a segue to move from a screen with a pickerview and a play button to the mainVC where there is a game. 
If the user wants to save the game, instead of unwinding the segue, the author adds another segue to go back to the previous controller calling:

```
@IBAction func mainMenu(){

    sqlite3_close(db)
    sqlite3_close(db2)
    //switch to picker view
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainMenuSegue", sender: nil)

}
```

It appears that the mainVC this function is in, is modally presented.
In my experimenting/learning, I embedded the whole project in a navigation controller, hence having a back button to move from the mainVC to the picker view controller.

Is there a way to accomplish the above function with the back button? 
Currently pressing the back button will take me to the picker, but does not reload the picker data if I save a game. I have to go one more back and return to the picker view to get the reloaded data.

Thanks

Comment: I tried with adding this in the mainVC so the sqlite is taken care of:

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if self.navigationController?.topViewController != self {
            sqlite3_close(db)
            sqlite3_close(db2)
        }
    }
but I need something to reload the picker data.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was looking at this the wrong way. 
If I press the back button, the db is updated anyway. My problem was on the loading the view to update the picker.